# How to prevent none images to be seen in browsing using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to do is if the user click to browse for files he should see images only no other files. How to do that using `jquery`?

My problem is I can see and choose other files besides images when i browse.

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/3123/

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#Picture').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your input to:

```
<input type='file' id="imgInp" accept="image/*" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/3124/