# If img tag is blank set a temporary image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do the following: if the user hasn't choose their profile image they will have a temporary image on their profile instead.

How to do it using jquery?

current output:  http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/3126/

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#Picture').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: can't you simply set a default image in the html itself? `<img src='default.png'/>`? you can override it once you get the source of user specified image.

Comment: A [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254480/how-to-prevent-none-images-to-be-seen-in-browsing-using-jquery), with an answer you've accepted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best options are without jQuery.

1. Set it in the HTML, if you don't have an `src` for the image, then put in your default image.

   ```
   <img src="default.png" id="Picture" />
   ```
2. Or you could set a background image using CSS.

   ```
   #Picture {
       background-image:url('default.png');
   }
   ```
3. But if you really want to do it with jquery then the following should work:

   ```
   var currentSrc = $('#Picture').attr('src');
   if(currentSrc==null || currentSrc==""){
       $('#Picture').attr('src','default.png');
   }
   ```

   If you need this on first load of the page, then put it instead a `$(document).ready()`.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var currentSrc = $('#Picture').attr('src');
       if(currentSrc==null || currentSrc==""){
           $('#Picture').attr('src','default.png');
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/3127/

you could set the src attribute on load, and overwrite it when the user selects another image

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <img src="https://www.google.nl/logos/doodles/2014/world-cup-2014-14-4668630004400128.5-hp.gif" id="Picture" data-src="#" /> <br />
         <input type='file' id="imgInp" accept="image/*" />
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `src` attribute exists on dom ready like this. Note that prividing a default image directly in the html code like the other answer states is much cleaner...

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#Picture').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    if (!$('#Picture').attr('src')){
        $('#Picture').attr('src', "http://placehold.it/120x120");
    }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/3129/

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this ?
i have update as per my understanding 
http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/3131/

```
if(e.target.result && input.files[0].type.indexOf("image/")>-1)
            {
             $('#Picture').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }else
            {
                 $('#Picture').attr('src',"http://www.w3schools.com/images/pulpit.jpg");

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use CSS method. define HTML as -

```
<img class="user-profile-avatar" src="">
```

and then you can define the avatar image in css -

```
.user-profile-avatar{
    background: url('YOUR_DEFAULT_AVATAR_IMAGE_URL') no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
    // additionally you can add height width to image for better results
    height: 300px;
    width: 240px;
}
```

this way, you dont need to load multiple images in HTML (not even from cache) which may happen if you use `<img src-"some_source">` and as soon as DOM is building and page started rendering you will be able to see default avatar image.

later on on page load, you can set the user image via JS.

or

use following way

HTML Code -

```
<div class="user-profile-avatar" data-profile-src="YOUR_USER_IMAGE_URL"></div>
```

CSS -

```
.user-profile-avatar{
    background: url('YOUR_DEFAULT_AVATAR_IMAGE_URL') no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
    // additionally you can add height width to image for better results
    height: 100px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

JS -

```
$(function(){
    $(".user-profile-avatar").each(function(){
        var el = $(this);
        var src = el.data("profile-src") != "" ? el.attr("data-profile-src") : "http://www.newportoak.com/wp-content/uploads/default-avatar.jpg";
        el.css({
            "background-image": "url('"+src+"')"
        });
    });
});
```

I used jQuery for ease of demo.  http://jsfiddle.net/Pu9NU/